# How to add an input tag with JS function in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, echo

I have the following code:

```
    echo ('
    <input onclick='responsiveVoice.speak("Hello World");' type='button' value=' Play'>
    ');
```

When the code is executed, I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'responsiveVoice' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\adiai\ai_main.php on line 70
```

I noticed that my IDE's colors are also getting 'mixed up'. I have a feeling that it is because of the ';' and several quotation marks within my echo statement.

How am I supposed to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have single quotes inside and outside your string which caused javascript to misunderstand. Use double quotes outside instead.

Using the `\` symbol could help too

```
echo ("
<input onclick='responsiveVoice.speak(\"Hello World\")' type='button' value=' Play'>
");
```